# What are the common dependencies of Weblogic 8.1.6

Tags: java, dependencies, weblogic

We still have to use Weblogic 8.1.6. There are some libraries packaged with the server, in `common/lib` but unfortunately there is only a `3rdparty.jar` inside it. The libraries take precedence, so if we use e.g. Apache Commons Lang 2.4 we get a `MethodNotFoundError` at runtime.

So what exactly is inside the `3rdparty.jar` and which versions?

If we would know we could define a POM with the weblogic common dependencies and "freeze" their version numbers, to see incompatibilities at compile time rather than runtime.

As I found out after more investigations, `3rdparty.jar` is not used, but most 3rd party libraries are packed into the `weblogic.jar` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found some dependencies for **WebLogic Server 8.1.6.0 SP6**: It is [J2EE 1.3 compliant](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/release/ReleaseNotes.html#9712), and from the javax stuff it contains:

- javax.activation - JAF 1.0.2 (21.5.1999)
- javax.connector - J2EE Connector 1.0
- javax.ejb - EJB 1.1 & 2.0 (30.11.2001)
- javax.jms - JMS 1.0.2b
- javax.mail - JavaMail 1.2 (28.6.2002)
- javax.management - JMX 1.0 (16.5.2006)
- javax.net
- javax.servlet Java Servlets 2.3, JSP 1.2 (7.11.2001)
- javax.jts/javax.transaction (jta) - Java Transaction API (JTA) 1.0, 1.0.1b, 1.2 ?
- javax.xml.messaging/soap/rpc - JAX-RPC 1.0

[Weblogic documentation](http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs81/notes/new.html#1196943) and the `weblogic.jar` give further:

- Ant 1.5.3
- org.apache.oro - Jakarta-oro 2.0.7
- antlr - Antlr 2.7.1
- com.sybase.jdbc - Sybase jConnect for JDBC 2.0 version 5.5 ?
- Oracle JDBC Driver 10.2.0.2.0
- com.rsa.certj - Cert-J 2.0.2 from certicom
- com.certicom - Certicom SSL 3.1.14
- com.rsa.jsafe - RSA Crypto-J 3.5 (Crypto-J.jsafefips.extension)
- netscape.ldap - Netscape LDAP 3.1
- com.adventnet - AdventNet SNMP 3.2.2 SP1
- org.mozilla.javascript/classfile - JavaScript 1.5 from Mozilla
- com.linar - JCom from J-Integra
- com.octetstring - Octetstring 1.5
- org.w3c.dom.ls/ranges - JAXP 1.1
- org.apache.xerces.dom3 - Apache Xerces DOM
- PointBase 4.3 (not found in jars)
- Acumen UDDI (not found in jars)
- net.n3.nanoxml - ?
- com.netscape.sasl - ?
- Jython

Comment: found more, but in their own namespace (weblogic.apache...):

 - Xerces 2.1.0
 - Xalan 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the jar - it should be obvious what classes are there. I don't have access to WebLogic but there should be some form of manifest inside which describes the packages and their versions.

Comment: inside the jar I can see ...apache.commons.lang etc. and others MIXED together (this really sucks). So I assume several common jars mixed together.
javax.xml.parser
org.apache.{log4j,wml,xerces,xml}
org.xml
org.mozilla
org.w3c
etc.

Comment: Yes, it should be a 'mixed' jar, which is a pain from many points of view. You can pretty much guess the packages, but if you have a manifest you can have the versions. Otherwise, it's useless.